# How do I do this query using metawhere and joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, meta-where

I have User.rb:

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sent_messageable_id"
```

Each Message.rb has an account_id and a :givereceive method:

```
belongs_to :account
```

I want to create a method for the Account.rb model so that I can show all the Users (uniquetly) who sent a message where the account_id is the same as that account and :givereceive = "Give"

I tried the following:

```
 User.joins(:sent_messages).where(
     {:sent_messages => [:account_id => self.account_id, 
                         :givereceive => "Give"]})
```

But I get an error that there is no association with Messages.

**Also, this wouldn't remove duplicate instances**  (for example, the same user created several messages with the same Account).

I am testing it in the console and have the metawhere gem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `joins(:messages)` to `joins(:sent_messages)`

```
 User.joins(:sent_messages).where(
     {:sent_messages => [:account_id => self.account_id, 
                         :givereceive => "Give"]})
```

Comment: how do I remove duplicates of Users?

Answer (score 0):

Add these associations to your models:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "sent_messageable_id"
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :give_messages, :class_name => "Message", :conditions => {:givereceive => "Give"}
  has_many :users, :through => :give_messages
end
```

Now to get the users you are looking for just call `@account.users`.